# Java format HTTP request in ByteBuffer

Tags: java

I want to format a HTTP request like this one into a `ByteBuffer`, so I can send it with `socket.getOutputStream.write()` instead of using a `PrintWriter`.

```
pw.println("GET / HTTP/1.1");
pw.println("Host: "+ip);
pw.println("User-Agent: Mozilla/1.22 (compatible; MSIE 2.0d; Windows NT)");
pw.println("");
pw.flush();
```

Comment: Did you ever look at Apache Commons HTTP Client. This should make your life much easier: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

Comment: I am aiming to do this through only sockets at the moment :) @ced-b

Comment: Alright if you really want to go hardcore lowlevel see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using a socket is really a requirement, I would use a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder mySb = new StringBuilder();
mySb.append("This is my Line\n");

socket.getOutputStream().write(mySb.toString().getBytes());
```

Comment: Would that be more efficient than a byte buffer? Or just the same.

Comment: My take is that it is slightly less efficient, but comes with a certain amount of programming comfort and better readability of your code, that for most applications makes up the damage. You would have to run a test of several thousand command executions to determine the difference.